# select avg(),min(),max(),toatl(),count() of selected result

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to calculate average,min,max,total,count but i am getting wrong result.

```
SELECT t0.brandID, t0.brandName, t0.cdt, t0.udt, t0.brandstatus, t0.AddedBy  ,
   AVG(t0.brandID) AS brandID_AVERAGE,
   min(t0.brandid) as branid_min,
   MAX(t0.brandid) as brandid_max,
   COUNT(t0.brandid) as brandid_count    
   FROM brands t0 
   Where  t0. brandID=null OR  t0. brandName='khasim'
   group by t0.brandID,t0.brandName,t0.cdt,t0.udt,t0.brandstatus,t0.AddedBy


select AVG(CAST (brandID AS bigint)) AS brandID_AVERAGE,
   min(CAST (brandID AS bigint)) as branid_min,
   MAX(CAST (brandID AS bigint)) as brandid_max,
   COUNT(CAST (brandID AS bigint)) as brandid_count    from
  (SELECT t0.brandID, t0.brandName, t0.cdt, t0.udt, t0.brandstatus, t0.AddedBy  

   FROM brands t0 
   Where  t0. brandID=null OR  t0. brandName='budwieser'
   group by t0.brandID,t0.brandName,t0.cdt,t0.udt,t0.brandstatus,t0.AddedBy) temptable
```

> i have changed my query to select avg etc for the result of select now
>   i am getting what i expect, but i want to show all selected columns in
>   one table how to do.

expected result
[image]

result for the above query is 
[image]

Comment: replace t0.brandid=null to is null

Comment: @TheGameiswar, make sure it is `t0.brandId is null`. The space between `is` and `null` is important.

Comment: Yes,that was type,i edited it long back

Answer (score 0):

Your first query where you're returning one row looks correct.  Your second screenshot where you get many rows looks like you are using `WINDOWING` functions (i.e. anything with an `OVER` clause).  This does not aggregate data, it returns all rows and repeats the calculations *over the set* while returning every row.

Can you include the full query text that is producing the incorrect result?

Also, it could be caused by `brandId` being an `integer` type, in which case all calculations on it will use integer-based arithmetic (i.e. no fractions).  This is fine if you only expect integer results, but if you need fractions, try using `CAST` to convert all the occurrences of `brandid` to decimal types, like this: `CAST(brandId as decimal(18, 8))` before doing the `AVG` and other calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly. From my best knowledge in SQL null is not equal to null. So you need to use `is null` to check is value equals to null. 
Secondly. Could you explain please what is wrong with underlined values?

Comment: i have updated my query and expected result can you please help

Comment: Looks like you can get expected results if you groups only by `brandName` column

Comment: i am building query based on user inputs if i am not adding groupby all selected columns i am getting error so i am grouping by all selected columns. how to make union of the both and show in one table.

Comment: try to reduce fields list to brandName and aggregate functions. And look on result. I.e. try to execute `select brandName, average(to.brandId) ..... group by brandName`

Comment: my first query is as you said and the result from the query is not the expected result, i have to find out the avg() etc of the result. can you help me joining the both select statement and show the result in one table. i have the rest of the result done. but if i do union i am getting error "All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.
"